# Android loading drawable instead of drawable-land even though orientation is landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this splash screen that displays an image for a few seconds before the main `Activity` starts, and it has a portrait version (drawable-hdpi/splash) and a landscape version (drawable-land-hdpi). The splash screen sets the orientation in the `onCreate()`.

### My issue:

If I have the tablet in Portrait mode and start the app, the splash screen rotates to landscape, but for some reason it loads the portrait drawable (still rotated to landscape) instead of the landscape version of the drawable, even though we're obviously in landscape mode. I'm guessing that somewhere android picks up that the device itself is still in portrait, and resolves drawable to the portrait version. Any clues how to get it to load the correct drawable?

### Code:

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</FrameLayout>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (DisplayUtils.isTablet(this)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);         
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }       

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

Relevant parts of the manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.foo.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: does it happen in the emulator? it's a known emulator bug.

Comment: Nope, on real devices (Nexus 7 to be precise)

Comment: maybe **w** instead of **sw** could help, since your device is EXACTLY 600dp, as read on the reference [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Yeah, that solved it :) drawable-sw600dp and putting in the landscape image in there. Thanks :)