# Android Loading Drawable Resources in Changing Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-image, android-drawable

I'm having problem in android while changing orientation. Android doesn't load the correct drawable for different orientation and sometimes the drawable resource is stuck on what the orientation it loads. For example I load my app in portrait in loads the image in my drawable port folder while I switch it on landscape it still uses the same drawable resources from port, same goes for landscape and sometimes it changes but after the 3rd orientation switch its stuck to what is loaded before. Somebody help me with this error

Comment: please show me your drawable all folder for potratit and landscape both

Comment: Here you go I have tablet layout for 7 and 10 inch both for landscape only while on phone i have both orientations

Comment: http://imgur.com/vdBq2em

Comment: I have the same problem as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503240/android-loading-drawable-instead-of-drawable-land-even-though-orientation-is-lan anyone can help me