# Where to put correct resources drawable for android? I'm getting wrong images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

Here's my drawable  [drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXIhb.jpg) I have 4 different layouts. 7 INCH Landscape tablet, 10 Inch Landscape tablet and Mobile Phone Portrait and Landscape. Where do i put the correct images according to layout in my drawable? Because I'm having a problem with phone landscape when I switch orientation to landscape it loads my phone portrait images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have drawables just for the tablet, you can add **drawable-sw600dp** and **drawable-sw720dp** that will be taken when taking layouts from **layout-sw600dp/layout-sw600dp-land** and **layout-sw720dp/layout-sw720dp-land**.

Basically, whatever you use for layouts, you can also use for drawables, those are generic qualifiers.

Comment: So far I have no problem with my tablet drawable but main problem is phone drawables. It does not load the correct images. Let say I start my phone in landscape it loads landscape images then when I switch it to portrait sometimes it still load the same landscape images or sometimes its working. Android Identify my images so wierd

Comment: Anyone have the same problem?  here's my latest drawable http://imgur.com/xDZAHkW

Comment: I have the same problem as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503240/android-loading-drawable-instead-of-drawable-land-even-though-orientation-is-lan anyone can help me

Comment: I think you should put the orientation qualifiers before the density, like for example **drawable-mdpi** for portrait and **drawable-land-mdpi** for landscape. I just tested it in Android studio and it works. BTW, you should be able to see it in the Android Studio layout editor, and if you're using the 0.8.6 and later, you can choose **New** when right clicking, and if you then choose **Android resource directory**, you get to pick from all the possible qualifiers you need (_Density_, _Orientation_) and the editor will put them in the right order, so you don't have to think about it.

Comment: Also, you're mixing the screen size qualifiers with density qualifiers. Try to put the landscape resources you want (which are, I presume, in the **drawable-normal-land**) into the **drawable-mdpi-land** or **drawable-land** and see what happens. I think that Android, when going through density qualifiers (_xhdpi_, _hdpi_, _mdpi_) doesn't fall back onto the default screen size qualifier (_normal_).

Comment: Ok Thanks btw I'm using Android Eclipse I think for my next project I'll use android studio. Eclipse is giving me too many problems will check it